# My InfoContributor is not sending info to Actuator endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to send more information to the `/info` endpoint:

```
@Component
public class InfoEndpoint implements InfoContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {
        Map<String, Integer> userDetails = new HashMap<>();
        userDetails.put("teste", 23);
        userDetails.put("teste2", 22);

        builder.withDetail( "menuitems", userDetails );
    }


}
```

but after accessing `http://myapp/actuator/info` I can't see the info. To do some testing I put some info data in `application.properties` like `info.app.name` and then I can see only this.

What I have done wrong?

Edit: [Here you can find my real project](https://github.com/icemagno/geoinfra/tree/master/hydra) (sorry: remarks in pt_BR). 
Edit: My entire POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.cmabreu</groupId>
    <artifactId>hydra</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>hydra</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>        


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>           

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: which version spring boot? @user

Comment: The code looks totally fine ([similar example](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-info-actuator-custom)) and it worked in my small example. Please check the versions of the spring libraries, run `mvn clean`, check that `InfoEndpoint` is reached by the spring component scan. If it doesn't work you can publish a small project showing the problem.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: can you post complete pom.xml @MagnoC

Comment: Done. See my edits.

Comment: @Sergii Zhevzhyk deleted all but `src` and `pom.xml`. Removed from Spring Tool Suite and then added again + `clean` + `Alt+F5 ( Maven | Update Project)`. All the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the log I found the following message:

```
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean 'infoEndpoint' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [br.com.cmabreu.InfoEndpoint]; defined in file [C:\...\hydra\target\classes\br\com\cmabreu\InfoEndpoint.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.info.InfoEndpointAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=infoEndpoint; defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/info/InfoEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]]
```

It looks like that your custom bean is substituted with the default bean because they have the same name. One solution is to change the name of the class, for example:

```
@Component
public class ExtendedInfoEndpoint implements InfoContributor {
    Map<String, Integer> userDetails = new HashMap<>();
    userDetails.put("teste", 23);
    userDetails.put("teste2", 22);      
    builder.withDetail( "menuitems", userDetails );
}
```

Another solution is to use the attribute's value:

```
@Component(value = "extendedInfoEndpoint")
public class InfoEndpoint implements InfoContributor {
    Map<String, Integer> userDetails = new HashMap<>();
    userDetails.put("teste", 23);
    userDetails.put("teste2", 22);      
    builder.withDetail( "menuitems", userDetails );
}
```

Comment: You're a wizard !!